# How to specify existing type or interface as part of function signature in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an existing callable interface:

```
interface MyCallback {
    (x: number): number;
}
```

And I have a function implementing this interface:

```
function myFunction(x: number): number {
    return x + 10;
}
```

The problem here is I have to needlessly repeat the information in the definition of myFunction. To reuse my type definition, I can use arrow function:

```
const myFunction2: MyCallback = (x) => x + 10;
```

However, I cannot use arrows all the time. **Is there any way I can specify existing interface/signature to the function definition**?

I need this because the interface I am trying to use is external. It is part of npm package. I don't wish to repeat that information everywhere in my code.

Comment: Is your objection to function expressions in general?  e.g., what about  `const myFunction: MyCallback = function (x) { return x + 10; }`?

Comment: No objection to arrows or function expressions. I need it more in ES classes where arrows or function expressions are not available. I have to use the plain old function syntax.

Comment: What @jcalz is saying is that `x` will be inferred for `=>` and for `functions` in the same way. You don't need to specify parameter types, if you use function expressions not declarations

Comment: The question should mention classes then, since if that's the issue, there's unfortunately [no way](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) to infer the argument types of a method.  You'll have to be redundant.

Comment: @jcalz, looks like the case as you mentioned.